# Can I post PDFs or other documents to my business's page on Facebook? 

Tags: facebook, pdf

Can I post PDFs or other documents to my business's page on Facebook? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly upload files to your business's page on Facebook.
What you can do though is post them to your wall – or – create a tab on the page with links to the PDFs.

Answer (score 4):

The document will need to be hosted somewhere outside of Facebook.  Then, you can post them as links on your wall. Simply copy and paste the URL to the document and it'll show up.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft actually released a Facebook integration project with Office 2010 web apps at [Docs.com](http://docs.com). It basically is a Facebook app that lets you share and collaborate on documents using the online Office 2010 web apps. More information [here](http://fuse.microsoft.com/projects-docs.html) and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Charles/Introducing-Docs-for-Facebook-Making-Your-Documents-Social/).

Answer (score -1):

There are several options:

`Docs.com` - based on Silverlight therefore won't work in Linux
`Edocr.com` - based on Flash therefore won't work on iPhone
`Share.kagoon.com` - based on HTML and working great.